# Get the return value of a javascript function from inside a form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this form

```
<form action="<?php echo $response ?>?nexturl=<?php echo $nexturl ?>"
 method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return saveFile(); ">
 <input id = "file" name="file" type="file" style="border:none;"/>
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
return $action = saveFile();
```

I want to store the return value of `saveFile()` Which is a JavaScript code that returns a boolean into a PHP variable. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preserve the value in hidden input field and then submit the form:
Like this:

```
function saveFile()
{
    var val=true;
    var input=document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    input.setAttribute("name", "booleanValue");
    input.setAttribute("value", val);
    document.getElementById("form").appendChild(input);
}
```

To retrieve this value in php:

```
$myBoolean=$_REQUEST['booleanValue'];
```

Comment: Can you show how I would call the created element from php?